# Getting undefined from state while using useEffect and useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, react-hooks, react-redux

My issue here is that sometimes my projects state is returning undefined sometimes. I am not sure why. As you can see, in the useEffect I have a function that gets project data from an API call to my backend server. This will then return an array of projects, which I then planned to see in the dom in the return statement. However, for whatever reason, upon the initial render it gives me an undefined and the screen goes white.

Strangely, enough, if I change the return statement to just display a regular string, let's say "hello" for example, save, and then change it back to {projects[0].name} it will then work. Yet on initial render I am getting a Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name');

I will add that I am getting a 304 status from my server in the console but that is because the data has not changed and thus I am receiving the previous UI from local storage if I remember correctly. This is not an issue with other parts of my application so I do not know why it would be an issue here.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { fetchPage } from "./../store/actions"
import { connect } from "react-redux"
/*import { ProjectCard } from "./../components/ProjectCard"*/
import API from './../api/API'
const Projects = ({ fetchPage }) => {
    const [projects, setProjects] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        const getProjectData = async () => {
            try {
                const { data } = await API.getAllProjects()
                setProjects(data.data)
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
        }
        fetchPage('Projects', "Here are your projects")
        getProjectData()
    }, [fetchPage])
    return (<div>
        {projects[0].name}
    </div>)
}

export default connect(null, { fetchPage })(Projects);
```

Here is a different part of my application that works more or less the same way

```
const [users, setUsers] = useState([])
    useEffect(() => {
        const getUserData = async () => {
            
                const { data } = await axios.get('/api/v1/users', {
                    headers: {
                        'Content-type': 'application/json'
                    }
                })
                setUsers(data.data.data)
            
        }
        fetchPage("TEAM", "Here is your team");
        getUserData();
    }, [fetchPage])
```

I tried removing the action creator which I expected did not work

Answer (score 0):

Projects starts as an empty array. Projects[0] will be undefined. Then you can't do `.name` on undefined.

Not saying there won't be other issues, but I'd say at least a good starting point would be to return a ternary, say `projects.length > 0 && ...`